# how to input a list of time series to correlation function in r

Tags: r

I have a **list** of **time series**:

```
ts1 <- ts(seq(1,12), start=c(2019,01), frequency=12)
ts2 <- ts(seq(12,26), start=c(2019,01), frequency=12)
ts3 <- ts(seq(24,30),start=c(2019,01), frequency=12)
list_ts <- list()
list_ts[["a"]] <- ts1
list_ts[["b"]] <- ts2
list_ts[["c"]] <- ts3
```

and I would like to obtain something with the same format as when specifying each element:

```
ts.intersect(ts1,ts2,ts3)
```

I tried this:

```
lapply(list_ts, ts.intersect)
```

but the output is not a matrix of ***time series*** as per my needs
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `do.call`

```
do.call(ts.intersect, list_ts)
#         a  b  c
#Jan 2019 1 12 24
#Feb 2019 2 13 25
#Mar 2019 3 14 26
#Apr 2019 4 15 27
#May 2019 5 16 28
#Jun 2019 6 17 29
#Jul 2019 7 18 30
```

---

Or with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(ts.intersect, list_ts)
```

---

Or using `reduce` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(list_ts, ts.intersect)
```

Comment: how could I create the list_ts by appending other lists on a lopp?

Comment: names_list <- names(ts1,ts2,ts3)
for(i in names_list){
  append(list_ts,i)
}